# Как сохранить файл через python (модуль requests)

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Есть ссылка, которая указывает на страницу от куда должно автоматически скачиваться файл с информацией.

Для этого я через модуль `requests` с функцией `get` отправляю запрос и сохраняю в переменную, чтобы эту самую информацию записать в другой файл, а потом уже анализировать.

Вот мой код:

```
f=open ("C:\\Users\\Hammer\\Desktop\\для сохранения содержимых.txt", 'wb')    
ufr=requests.get('https://stepic.org/media/attachments/course67/3.6.3/699991.txt')    
f.write(ufr.content)    
f.close()      
print(f.read)
```

А вот,  что мне выдает:

```
https://stepic.org/media/attachments/course67/3.6.3/699991.txt

<built-in method read of _io.BufferedWriter object at 0x03475228>
```

Comment: а за чем вы пишите в начале каждой строки `введите сюда код`?

Comment: @timur это когда в редакторе нажимаешь "Выделить как код" появляется строка с такой надписью и код, вставленный вместо неё будет отформатирован. А ТС видимо не вставил ничего вместо надписи `:)`

Comment: а что-то по-поводу решения будет?

Comment: Ссылка какая-то странная. Там файл, в котором просто "213837.txt". Вам точно оно нужно?

Comment: Используйте `with`, используйте `pathlib`

Answer (score 3):

read это метод, ты забыл скобки,
напиши вот так

```py
f = open ("C:\\Users\\Hammer\\Desktop\\для сохранения содержимых.txt", 'wb')
ufr = requests.get('https://stepic.org/media/attachments/course67/3.6.3/699991.txt')
f.write(ufr.content)
f.close()
f = open ("C:\\Users\\Hammer\\Desktop\\для сохранения содержимых.txt", 'r')
print(f.read())
```

и все заработает

Comment: Типичный случай в Питоне )